# Why does this device always reboot at 21:17?

Tags: raspbian, boot, monitoring

My Raspberry Pi has been rebooting itself a lot lately and I can't seem to figure out what is happening.
Here's the output of **last -x**:

```
hal@raspberrypi ~ $ last -x
hal pts/10            localhost        Wed May 21 14:13   still logged in   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Tue May 20 21:17 - 14:56  (17:39)    
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Tue May 20 21:17 - 14:56  (17:39)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Mon May 19 21:17 - 21:17 (1+00:00)   
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Mon May 19 21:17 - 14:56 (1+17:39)   
hal pts/6             localhost        Mon May 19 11:25 - 11:37  (00:12)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Sun May 18 21:17 - 21:17 (1+00:00)   
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Sun May 18 21:17 - 14:56 (2+17:39)   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Sat May 17 23:17 - 21:17  (22:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Sat May 17 23:17 - 14:56 (3+15:39)   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Fri May 16 23:17 - 23:17 (1+00:00)   
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Fri May 16 23:17 - 14:56 (4+15:39)   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Thu May 15 21:17 - 23:17 (1+01:59)   
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Thu May 15 21:17 - 14:56 (5+17:39)   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Wed May 14 21:17 - 21:17  (23:59)    
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Wed May 14 21:17 - 14:56 (6+17:39)   
hal pts/12            localhost        Wed May 14 15:07 - 15:10  (00:02)
```

From my understanding, the device has been rebooting once a day at either 21:17 ou 23:17 and it stays online for over a day, right?

Moreover, on May 16th the system was online for 4 days (last column), right? How can this be if I've got a reboot entry for both the previous and the following days?!

Running **last reboot** yields similar results: http://pastebin.com/F1ZUBpyf

Moreover, I've actually got a reboot scheduled, but its scheduled to 3AM:

```
0 3 * * * /sbin/reboot -h
```

I've been looking through the system logs, but so far no such luck.
Any ideas what might be going on?

**Edit:** Last night, the Raspberry felt creative and rebooted at 22:17, even though i removed the 3AM boot.

Here's the output of last:

```
hal pts/6        localhost        Thu May 22 10:42   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Wed May 21 22:17 - 11:33  (13:15)    
hal pts/3        localhost        Wed May 21 16:25 - 16:45  (00:20)    
hal pts/6        localhost        Wed May 21 15:22 - 16:18  (00:56)    
hal pts/10       localhost        Wed May 21 14:13 - 15:11  (00:58)    
reboot   system boot  3.6.11-atsw-rtc+ Tue May 20 21:17 - 11:33 (1+14:15)
```

and [here's a pastebin containing the full /var/log/syslog of today](http://pastebin.com/X7GJnsPV).

[I checked all of the cron jobs of all users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134944/89825) and everything checks out. added an extra command to measure the temperature every minute, here's its cronjob:

- - - - - echo $(date -u) ";" $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp) >> /home/hal/temperature.txt

The temperature is currently a 69ºC by the way.

**Edit 2:**
Running  *grep CRON /var/log/syslog* yielded an interesting result:

```
May 21 22:17:18 raspberrypi /usr/sbin/cron[1962]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
May 21 22:17:18 raspberrypi /usr/sbin/cron[1965]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
May 21 22:17:18 raspberrypi /usr/sbin/cron[1965]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

**Edit 3:** Apparently, that last line only shows up *after* a system boot; [it doesn't reboot the Raspberry itself](https://askubuntu.com/a/391982)

Comment: Just an idea, but could it have something to do with the RPi not having an RTC? I don't know wheter these timestamps are created before or after syncing to a timeserver. It might also be a good idea to check your timezone (running raspbian, I think that the config program can do this).

Comment: Well, it does have an RTC, a Rasclock. The timezone was Europe/Lisbon, but I've just changed it to GMT+1 in any case.

Comment: If you're running syslog, what does `/var/log/syslog` show just before the time of the reboot or around that time or grep syslog for CRON using `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and syslog.1

Comment: Just added more info, thank you for your time. I've found out a very interesting entry in this log, check it out.

Comment: Hmm. Just a thought: what _else_ is connected to the same power source - that is, the same part of your house wiring - as the pi? Can there be something that steals enough power and 17 minutes past full our in the evenings to starve the pi?

Comment: You could verify power source issues by connecting a second RasPi with default operating system to the same power outlet. Or swap the SD card of your first RasPi with a default image you download from the RasPi website.

Comment: I ended up formatting and reinstalling Raspbian and the problem went away, but i'll keep that in mind @AmedeeVanGasse, nicely put. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up formatting and reinstalling Raspbian and the problem went away.
Never did manage to determine the cause of these reboots.